# Internet connection slows/hangs intermittently

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, router, internet

Over the last few days I've been having internet connectivity problems.  The connection seems to hang for a random length of time, up to about 1 minute.  This happens at random intervals, the shortest being around every 2 minutes and the longest about 10-15.

My wireless icon shows as 5 bars and connected throughout these hangs, then at the end of the hang it flicks down to 4 bars and back to 5 again - this could mean nothing though.

I have contacted my ISP and they remotely logged into the router and after tweaking a few minor settings say they found no issues.

I have updated the drivers for the wireless card (Intel WiFi Link 5100 AGN) but this didn't change anything.

In the device manager, I made sure the wireless card power management settings unchecked "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power", so this isn't the problem.

There are 5 other computers in this house connected to the wireless router and having no issues.

I'm running Windows 8 on an Acer laptop and have had no recent hardware or software changes.

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: How do you judge that your internet connection hangs exactly?  If no other computer has a problem, this indicates, a hardware problem on the computer in question.

Comment: Is the computer having trouble resolving DNS entries?

Comment: @Ramhound I judge the hang because as I'm browsing various websites everything stops and I get the loading icon.  Sometimes I get the "cannot load webpage" error too and my webmail gives me a "cannot connect right now" during the hangs

Comment: @DarthAndroid How would I check if this is the case?

Comment: @peacemaker - I had a similar issue and turned out my hdd was going bad.

Comment: @Ramhound Interesting, I've had the laptop a couple of years so perhaps I should be aware of that.

Comment: @peacemaker You can try a tool like [Namebench](https://code.google.com/p/namebench/) or if you're using Chrome, just look at the status popup when you navigate to a page and the connection seems to hang, it should tell you that it's trying to resolve whatever website you just navigated to.

Comment: @eacemaker - If all that happens is you press refresh and it takes forever to load, then its unlikely a hdd problem, its just the description of what happens was similar to what happen to me.  Before you act upon what might not even be the problem verify your DNS isn't the problem first.

Comment: So the DNS looks fine, no issues resolving.  Of course, now I'm actively testing this issue it decides not to hang for the last 30 minutes!

Comment: It just happened again and I got the Chrome "Website wouldn't load" error with a strange error code: ERR_SPDY_PING_FAILED